# What can be wrong with release build, that make cause problems with UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, height, release

I have a `UIViewController` with `UIViewTableView` on it. When I test the app in debug scheme - everything works - cells are fine and can be selected. However, when I build release - some of the cells are disappeared and none of the cells can be selected

Everything is as it should be in `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
tableView.allowsSelection = true
```

It happened after Xcode update to Version 10.2 (10E125)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is very broad and it's unlikely somebody can help you. Please improve your question by adding the relevant code and better describing the differences between the release and debug version.

Comment: I think you looked for this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592341/xcode-10-2-protocol-inheritance-issue/55593277#55593277

Comment: @user11362050 thanks!